# Layout/indexing issue?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, indexing

On my website I have a div which animates in via a jQuery `click` function and it should show up over other divs which have animated in on `$(document).ready()`. However, it shows up behind these divs ONLY on my website's home page and NOT on any other page, only on mobile devices.

On homepage:

[image]

On any other page:

[image]

The only difference between the two types of pages is that on the home page, the navigation menu and the looseleaf div animate in like so

For the navigation menu:

```
setTimeout(function(){  
            $('#avmenu ul li').each(function(i) {
                var $fc = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $fc.addClass('flipInBottomBack').css({'pointer-events':'auto'});
                    }, i*250); // delay 250 ms
                });
            }, 6000);
```

With `flipInBottomBack` being a CSS keyframe animation with `opacity: 0` at the beginning, transitioning to `opacity: 1`.

While the looseleaf div animates in via CSS keyframe animation with a delay set in the animation class itself. It has the following CSS styles:

```
#welcome-box {
    width: 681px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    background: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ab9udqlsxbxaelw/LooseLeafExtended.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #000;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

On any other page, they are merely shown by removing the animation class for the looseleaf div, and by executing this code for the navigation menu:

```
$('#avmenu ul li').show().css({'opacity':'1'});
```

I have played around with the CSS index attribute, but it doesn't seem to work even when the homework div has the highest index. Why is it that it the div shows as desired on every page but the homepage?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set a `z-index` for your divs to properly order the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please include z-index on your code.

```
#welcome-box {
width: 681px;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
background: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ab9udqlsxbxaelw/LooseLeafExtended.png);
background-size: cover;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #000;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 12;
}
```

the value of z-index may change based on the upper div.